# How can I rename a Zarr array without writing new store?

Tags: python, python-xarray, zarr

I have a Zarr datastore, but I need to rename one of the dimensions. Let's say I have this ([from xarray docs](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#creating-a-dataarray)):

```py
data = np.random.rand(4, 3)
locs = ["IA", "IL", "IN"]
times = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=4)

da = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[times, locs], dims=["time", "space"])
ds = xr.Dataset({'my_var': da})
ds.to_zarr("my_zarr.zarr")
```

[image: dataset output screenshot]

But I want to my `space` dimension to actually to be called `state`.

And I don't want to write a *new* Zarr store, I just want to change that one name.

How can I do that? (I've found one hacky way - see below)

Answer (score 1):

While your answer will work @j sad, it's worth noting that there's a programmatic way to rename variables in via `zarr`'s API:

```
store = zarr.open("my_zarr.zarr")
zarr.storage.rename(store, 'my_var', 'my_new_var')
```

This will rename a variable, simply by copying the data from the old name's folder into a new name folder and deleting the old -- essentially replacing the manual approach *if* the only goal is to rename a variable.

Your question is actually more complex because you are attempting to rename a dimension of the dataset shared across variables.  Unfortunately, while you can use `zarr.storage.rename` to rename the coordinate array associated with the dimension you want to rename, it will not rename references to this dimension within variables in the way that `xarray` is expecting. Thus, the "Manually rename the dimension in the relevant .zattts files" step is still needed, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

My hacky solution is to rename them manually:

1. Rename the directory

```
cd my_zarr.zarr
mv space state
```

2. Manually rename the dimension in the relevant `.zattts` files:

OLD `my_zarr.zarr/my_var/.zattrs`

```
{
    "_ARRAY_DIMENSIONS": [
        "time",
        "space"
    ]
}
```

OLD `my_zarr.zarr/state/.zattrs`

```
{
    "_ARRAY_DIMENSIONS": [
        "space"
    ]
}
```

NEW `my_zarr.zarr/my_var/.zattrs`

```
{
    "_ARRAY_DIMENSIONS": [
        "time",
        "state"
    ]
}
```

NEW `my_zarr.zarr/state/.zattrs`

```
{
    "_ARRAY_DIMENSIONS": [
        "state"
    ]
}
```

And voila:
[image: dataset output]

But that's pretty hacky and I don't like how manual it is. It beats writing a whole new zarr store, but is there a better way?